# Add circle to pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm stuck with this in the past 2 weeks. I've been browsing all StackOverflow questions about updating the pack layout and similars and I read the d3js documentation about it and the update pattern, but none of them solve this problem and I really can't append a new element to the pack layout without redrawing everything.

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v74qp3a7/1/

```
var diameter = 300;

// The layout I'm using now
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
  .value(function(d) { return 1 });

// The basic container
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");

// My initial data source
var data = {
  name: "Languages",
  children: [{
    name: "Functional",
    children: [
      { name: "OCaml" },
      { name: "Haskell" },
      { name: "Erlang" }
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Imperative",
    children: [
      { name: "BASIC" },
      { name: "Clipper" }
    ]
  }]
};


// The node basis
var node = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
  .data(pack.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  });

function addToRoot(obj) {
  // Modify the current data object
  data.children.push(obj);

  // I try to modify by entering the node and applying a transition
  svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r;
    });
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

I read about `enter` and `exit`, but I didn't figure out how I can **update** the **data object** (not the data properties, that is pretty simple). I've been trying to use the three update patterns and got no results.

How can I add a simple element and update the graphical interface without redrawing everything when I call `addToRoot({ name: "foo" })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your selector relies on a class that you're never assigning to the circles in question. Hence, your selection will always be empty and simply add everything again. Second, you need to handle the update selection as well, not just the enter selection.

```
var sel = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
  .data(pack.nodes);

sel.enter().append("circle")
  .classed("node", true);
sel
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  });
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v74qp3a7/2/).

Comment: JSFiddle has this annoying habit of load scripts from insecure sources on secure sites. You need to allow unsafe scripts.